# how to deploy from dev to staging and production?

Tags: deployment

Hello so here is my question, 
I have three environments for my drupal 7 installation **Dev, Staging, Production**, right now Dev has all the new code and well everything is setup there. The move of the code from Dev to Sta or Prod is quite simple as it is just code and can be done with a simple push. But what about the configuration on the DB? how do you move DB configuration from Dev to Sta and Prod? more specifically how do you sync the configuration from Dev to Sta or Prod? so the views, nodes and whatever modules you had enabled on Dev will show on Sta or Prod?

Tried features and well it moved the code (which i already know how) but the db configuration was not transferred/enabled in the other environment

Comment: "but the db configuration was not transferred/enabled in the other environment". This seems to be your actual question regarding the features module. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Features should move the configuration in the db for any modules that are Features aware. What are you trying to move that's not supported in Features?

Comment: @mradcliffe i exported the content (views) through features, installed the module on the other environment and although the views appear on the content list in the admin module, if i click the links it takes me to the old views and not the new ones, what am i missing? that's what i mean the DB configuration

Comment: Does features still need the `revert` command run on it? `drush features-revert` or going to the feaure page in the UI to revert.

Comment: @mradcliffe will do the revert see if that helps. will a restore of everything but the roles/users work? right now the site is almost new there are no comments nor anything is just a major content upgrade but i still need to maintain current users and their roles

Answer (score 1):

Any deployment strategy can be broken down primarly into three main streams

- Content(Node,taxonomies etc.)
- Code
- Configuration(Content types, Vocabularies etc.)

**Content Deployment**

I am assuming you are not targeting content deployment as part of your deployment. Its a complex peace based on your content strategy.

**Configuration Deployment**

Configuration Deployment, since content and configuration are kind of tightly coupled till Drupal 7, there is no way out of the box you can just keep the configurations in sync. But there are couple of modules which let you pull your configuration into code, features is definitely one and I believe most widely used module for deployment.
Sometime you can not get all the configurations just by features module, there is another helper module [strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) module which will let you exporting variable configurations by contributed module.

Just wanted to bring the keypoints for feature module.

- Features module let you bring the configuration in code.
- Either you update your feature or revert your feature based on if you want to get the configurations as in feature code and revert any manual override configuration we do feature revert, if you want to get the manual updated configuration in feature code we do feature update/recreate.
- Feature module compares the configuration in code and configuration in database, based on it features allow to revert/update.

**Code Deployment**

For code any versioning tool will do the job.